Regex to split string along &
I have this string
PENNER,JANET E TR-50% & PENNER,MICHAEL G TR - 50% & SOURCE LLC & LARRY & FREDDY INC

and I want to split it up into groups like this
PENNER,JANET E TR

PENNER,MICHAEL G TR

SOURCE LLC

LARRY & FREDDY INC

I'm using javascript (node) with matchAll
and this is my attempt so far
/\s*([^&]+) ((L.?L.?C.?)|(T.?R.?)|(I.?N.?C.?)|(C.?O.?)|(REV LIV))(?=-)?/g

The hard part is that some business names include ampersands (&) so how would I do this?

Is there some resource that allows you to compare potential split strings with business names? Or is there a constant that is always present within the string that delineates potential business names, like perhaps the percentage point?

@dalelandry there's nothing to compare to and yes the % could possibly be used to delineate the end of a business name like "% &" or "LLC &"

Step 1 is to identify the rules (generally expressed in words) you wish to apply to extract the strings of interest. Step 2 is to construct a regular expression that implements those rules. We can with Step 2, but Step 1 is your job, and it obviously must be completed before moving on to Step 2.

/(?<=% )& | (?<=LLC )& /g  split using a regex with a look behind using the literal strings that would split the names into separate strings though, i have a feeling this is not going to accommodate all potential business names unless you can account for all potential splitting occurrences.

@samsun96 ... Regarding all the answers / solutions, are there any questions left?

A Positive Lookbehind (?<=% )& that matches a percentage operator and space followed by an ampersand operator and space => % & , then you can use the same logic with an OR regex operator | using the the literal string LLC and space followed by an ampersand space => LLC & . Then split the string using this regex => str.split(regex).
const regex = / (?<=% )& | (?<=LLC )& /g;

It is very straightforward and will not likely accommodate all potential occurrences of names in your string, though you can always add more logic if needed to the regex using the same positive look behind => ?<=


const str = 'PENNER,JANET E TR-50% & PENNER,MICHAEL G TR - 50% & SOURCE LLC & LARRY & FREDDY INC & SOMEBUSINESS,JOHN T TR - 75%';
// just add your positive lookbehind to accommodate new 'endings' in your business naming scheme
// I add a positive look behind for INC with a space followed by an ampersand and space
// provided this rule is always constant this approach should work
const regex = / (?<=% )& | (?<=LLC )& | (?<=INC )& /g; 
const results = str.split(regex);

console.log(results);



A dynamic version that would take in rules for the ending portion with which you wish to split the string into it's parts:
ie: %, INC, LLC, etc...


const str = 'PENNER,JANET E TR-50% & PENNER,MICHAEL G TR - 50% & SOURCE LLC & LARRY & FREDDY INC & SOMEBUSINESS,JOHN T TR - 75%';

// add an array with the matches for the possible endings
// this should work provided you use the same logic of ending followed by a space + positive lookbehind of & with a space 
const matches = ['%', 'LLC', 'INC']

// function to take in the array of endings
const dynamicRegex = (arr) => {
  // empty array to hold result
  let result = []
  // push each end into the result and build the regex string
  arr.forEach(end => result.push(` (?<=${end} )& `));
  // return regex string
  return result;
}

// join the result of the looped endings into a string
const joined = `${dynamicRegex(matches).join('|')}`;
// create a new regexp pattern and format 
const reg = new RegExp(joined, 'g')
// split the string using the regex and return an array of the desired output
const results = str.split(reg);

console.log(results)




Judging by your description, maybe this regex could work for you:
(?!\s|[^A-Z]*&).+? (?:L\.?L\.?C\.?|T\.?R\.?|I\.?N\.?C\.?|C\.?O\.?|REV LIV)



const text = 'PENNER,JANET E TR-50% & PENNER,MICHAEL G TR - 50% & SOURCE LLC & LARRY & FREDDY INC';

const regex = /(?!\s|[^A-Z]*&).+? (?:L\.?L\.?C\.?|T\.?R\.?|I\.?N\.?C\.?|C\.?O\.?|REV LIV)/g;

const companies = text.match(regex);

console.log(companies);




From the limited information upon which criteria on has to split a string, the most generic, yet precise enough regex one can come up with might look similar to ...
/\s*-.*?\s+&\s+|(?<=INC|LLC)\s+&\s+/g

... and that ...

/\s*-.*?\s+&\s+/g ... either does split at a minus char which is preceded by an optional whitespace sequence and followed by any sequence that does not contain an ampersand char until up to the next occurring whitespace-ampersand-whitespace sequence.

/(?<=INC|LLC)\s+&\s+/g ... or which splits at any whitespace-ampersand-whitespace sequence which is preceded by either and LLC or an INC abbreviation where the latter pattern does utilize a positive lookbehind (can I use Lookbehind in JS regular expressions).




const sampleText =
  'PENNER,JANET E TR-50% & PENNER,MICHAEL G TR - 50% & SOURCE LLC & LARRY & FREDDY INC';

const regXSplit =
  // see ... [https://regex101.com/r/xM9elf/1]
  /\s*-.*?\s+&\s+|(?<=INC|LLC)\s+&\s+/g;

console.log(
  sampleText.split(regXSplit)
);
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }




If a positive lookbehind is supported for your  environment, you could split using:
(?:\s*-\s*\d+%|(?<=\bLLC))\s*&\s*

The pattern matches:

(?: Non capture group for the 2 alternatives:

\s*-\s* Match a hyphen between optional whitespace chars
\d+% Match 1+ digits followed by a percentage sign
| Or
(?<=\bLLC) Positive lookbehind, assert LLC directly to the left


) Close non capture group
\s*&\s* Match an ampersand between optional whitespace chars

Regex demo


const s = `PENNER,JANET E TR-50% & PENNER,MICHAEL G TR - 50% & SOURCE LLC & LARRY & FREDDY INC`;
const regex = /(?:\s*-\s*\d+%|(?<=\bLLC))\s*&\s*/;
console.log(s.split(regex));



Example with all the alternatives:
(?:\s*-\s*\d+%|(?<=\b(?:L\.?L\.?C|T\.?R|I\.?N\.?C|C\.?O)\.?|\bREV LIV))\s*&\s*

Regex demo

I think OP meant not just LLC, any organization suffix in the list (TR, INC etc.) should also satisfy this rule

@HaoWu Yes you are right, I extended the list of alternatives
